# How can I determine if a delegate is an anonymous lambda?

Tags: .net, delegates, lambda

We have a library that imitates events and provides some enhanced functionality. It does this mainly by keeping track of delegates you register with it. Like events it has the potential for memory leaks.

I'm changing the class that managers the delegates over to using weak references but I'm running into a problem: if you register an anonymous lambda and `GC.Collect` the delegate gets collected. I'd like to programmatically determine if a delegate being registered is an anonymous lambda and use a strong reference instead for that case.

**Q:** How can I determine if a delegate is an anonymous lambda (or more generally, something that semantically we wouldn't expect to have it 'disappear' right away).

One way that might work is checking if the `Delegate.Target` property is null, but this catches static methods in general, so that might not be what I want. The other option is check if `IsSpecialName` and `IsStatic` are set to true on the `Delegate.Method` property. Not sure if that's the right thing to do either.

One concern is that if I have strong references to lambdas using members of the class it was registered in, we'll still end up with the same memory-leak scenario... or we might access a disposed object. Is there a graceful way to handle this?

Comment: `Delegate.Target` will not be null for lambdas with closures.

Comment: You should provide a way to unregister the event. If a user does not unregister, he's the one to blame for the memory leak, not you. Trying to be super-smart about lambdas vs. other delegates does not pay off: a lambda can easily cause a leak simply by referencing a field of the class in which it is created.

Comment: There is a way to unregister the event. I was just hoping to provide a level of convenience by not requiring that, but it sounds like I might have been a bit naive in my optimism and that this could cause more problems than it solves ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. At run-time anonymous lambda's *are* methods. You could check the method name:

```
static int Foo() { return 0; }

void Main()
{
    Func<int> foo = Foo;
    Func<int> bar = () => 0;
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Method.Name); // Foo
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Method.Name); // <Main>b__0
}
```

That's a pretty bad approach, but it may be the only way since `foo` and `bar` are otherwise indistinguishable.

Comment: @JeffBridgman I tried it. It's `false` for both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Weird, in VB.NET if I translate `bar` as `Dim bar As Func(Of Integer) = Function() 0` and add `Console.WriteLine(bar.Method.IsSpecialName)`, it'll print true. That's kind of horrible! Any idea what's happening? Did I mistranslate?

Comment: @JeffBridgman I suppose it's just a matter of differences in between the C# and VB.NET compiler. The generated name of the anonymous in VB.NET is `_Lambda$__1`, so if you go this route you'd probably need to try to handle both cases.